# how can k8s on mesos proxy on slave node？

Tags: kubernetes, mesos

k8s use kube-proxy and iptables to achieve loadbalance on slave node .
But on mesos, I remembered I am just install a kubemaster on meoso master and do nothing in mesos-slave . And how it can   proxy  well   without nothing installed on slave node ?

Answer (score 1):

The kubernetes-mesos framework assumes responsibility for spawning both the kubelet and kube-proxy processes on mesos slaves to support the pods (tasks) running there. Please refer to the architecture docs here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/contrib/mesos/docs/architecture.md